# Parallel Copy to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

What is the best and fast way to achieve parallel copy to hadoop from an NFS mount?
We have a mount with huge number of files and we need to copy it into hdfs.

Some options:

1. Run copyFromLocal in a multithreaded way
2. Use distcp in an isolated way.
3. Can i write a map only job to do copy?

Regards,
JD

Comment: Probably a test on real hardware in you situation would be the best way to go.

Comment: I am planning to use distcp -f <file:///list of URIS> <hdfs://URI> The number of files in the source list would be in millions. I dont know how would be the performance :(

Comment: M/R job would probably have the lowest performance. Why you don't want to merge those files before copying them to HDFS? If you have millions of files I assume, they are very small.

Comment: Yes they are small.Merging them using perl seems to be very costly process, so we are planning to copy them to hadoop and then run a PIG job to merge periodically. So you feel distcp would slower, then should be try run -copyFromLocal in a multithreaded way

Comment: For Reference http://jagaraniscrazy.blogspot.com/

Comment: I'm merging about 10-15k files (a few MB each) using only `cat *.in > big.out` and it takes up to a few minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key question is what is on the source side of the NFS link?  If it is a NAS you are likely to be better off with a situation where you have several client machines running copyFromLocal at the same time (one each).  Even high performance NASs are going to be displeased when you have more than 5-10 simultaneous disk reads from the same client.  I would model the following (all with copyFromLocal):

- NAS -> 1 Client -> 5, 10, 50, 100 parallel processes
- NAS -> 5 Clients -> 5, 10, 50, 100 parallel processes each

I would definitely avoid M/R as the process startup cost is too high and even distcp won't do as well because you won't be able to control how heavily the source NAS is hit (this will be your bottleneck).